# I am getting fatal error helper data not found

Tags: magento-1.9, fatal-error

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Bms_Banners_Helper_Data' not found in /var/www/html/app/Mage.php:547

But there is no Bms_Banners module

please help

Answer (score 0):

Some of the attributes could use this class.

On the first place you can check do you have any attributes in the backend.
Look for something related with bms banner.

Of course, if you can log in to backend if not you need run database search
for this class "Bms_Banners_Helper_Data"

Answer (score 0):

Add a new  Data.php file on Helper directory.

Bms/Banners/Helper/Data.php
with the follwing content.

```
<?php
class Bms_Banners_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{ 
}
```